# how can i fetch the data of the complex criteria api with the optional filters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, criteria-api

I have a requirement to list all the users, when i have to filter by the following:

1. Filter By FirstName()
2. Filter By LastName()
3. Filter By Department()

That's easily i have done by using something like this,

```
Employee
id()    firstName() lastName()
1       Victor      More
2       Peter       Gade    

EmployeeDepartment(one(Employee) to one(Department))
employeeId departmentId
1           1
2           2   

EmployeeAddress(one(Employee) to many(Address))
id employeeId doorNo streetName    cityName 
1   1         #12     South Lane   Newyork  
2   1         #13     North Lane   Chicago
```

this is my Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public PageResponse<BaseEmployeeDetail> getEmployees(
            @RequestParam(value = "pageNumber", required = false) Integer pageNumber,
            @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = false) Integer pageSize,
            @RequestParam(value = "search") String search) {

        if (pageNumber == null || pageNumber <= 0) {
            pageNumber = 1;
        }
        if (pageSize == null || pageSize <= 0) {
            pageSize = 10;
        }

        List<EmployeeSearchCriteria> params = new ArrayList<EmployeeSearchCriteria>();
        if (search != null) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+?)(:|<|>)(\\w+?),");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(search + ",");
            while (matcher.find()) {
                params.add(new EmployeeSearchCriteria(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3)));
            }
        }
        EmployeeDetail employeeDetails = employeeService.getEmployees(params, pageNumber, pageSize);
        .......
        .......
        return response;
    }
```

this is my implementation class,

```
@Override
    public EmployeeDetail getEmployees(List<EmployeeSearchCriteria> params,
            Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize) {
        final CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<CampaignDetail> query = builder.createQuery(User.class);
        final Root r = query.from(Employee.class);


        Join<Employee, EmployeeDepartment> employeeDepartment = employee.join("employeeDepartments",
                JoinType.LEFT);


        Join<EmployeeAddress, Address> address = r.join("address", JoinType.LEFT);

        // isDataEntered or isPartialDataEntered

        Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();
        for (final EmployeeSearchCriteria param : params) {

            if (param.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(">")) {
                predicate = builder.and(predicate,
                        builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(r.get(param.getKey()), param.getValue().toString()));
            } else if (param.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase("<")) {
                predicate = builder.and(predicate,
                        builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(r.get(param.getKey()), param.getValue().toString()));
            } else if (param.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(":")) {

                if (param.getKey().equals("firstName") || param.getKey().equals("lastName")) { //employees table

                        if (user.get(param.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
                            predicate = builder.and(predicate,
                                    builder.like(user.get(param.getKey()), "%" + param.getValue() + "%"));
                        } else {
                            predicate = builder.and(predicate,
                                    builder.equal(user.get(param.getKey()), param.getValue()));
                        }

                } else if (param.getKey().equals("departmentId")) { // employee_departments table
                    if (employeeDepartment.get(param.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {

                        predicate = builder.and(predicate,
                                builder.equal(employeeDepartment.get(param.getKey()), param.getValue()));
                    }

                }  
            }
        }
        query.where(predicate);
        Query query2 = entityManager.createQuery(query);
        query2.setFirstResult((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize);
        query2.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        Long countResult = (long) entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList().size();
        EmployeeDetail employeeDetail = new EmployeeDetail();
        employeeDetail.setTotalEmployeeCount(countResult);
        employeeDetail.setEmployeeDetail(query2.getResultList());
        return employeeDetail;

    }
```

this is my Endpoint:

```
http://localhost:8080/employees?search=firstName:Peter,lastName:Gade,departmentId:4
```

but, when i have to filter with the following requirement, i struggle to find the results, how can i do this, can someone help me on this, here in the below filters are the optional one.,

```
1. Filter By FirstName()
2. Filter By LastName()
3. Filter By Department()

4. Filter By 
   (i)  AddressExist (Employees who hold addres row)
   (ii) AddressNotExist (Employees who doesnt hold address)
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? You know that you can add some debug points to `getEmployees` method to see if you are parsing the parameters as expected, check the query and the response coming back.

Comment: but how can i find the result for address exist or not exist filter?